# How can I create environment variables and use them in a react library, without using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have tried dotenv and cros-env. And also with mentioning it in this link

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

However, it doesn't work for me

My .env file

```
MY_VAR=value
```

I have this in the file where I want to call it

```
console.log(process.env)
const { MY_VAR } = process.env
console.log(MY_VAR)
```

and i get this

[image]

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, do you get an error? that should work

Comment: I don't get any error, just my variable is undefined

Comment: Please show an example of your code, but first another question, are you trying to access the environment variable at run time or build time?

Comment: I am trying to access it at run time

Comment: Environment variables run on the server, react runs on the client. You need to have some method to bundle the settings you want with the code. The link shows how to pull it off with create-react-app, which is running webpack (IIRC)

Comment: So, are you using the method outlined in [this section](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html) of the link you shared? since it links to a different page, I assume you haven't read that - i.e. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags#generating-dynamic-meta-tags-on-the-server

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), environment variables for your frontend must begin with `REACT_APP`. So try `REACT_APP_MY_VAR` and restart your React server afterwards.